# Cocoa - Error when importing a header file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am working in a project with multiple classes. Upon importing one of the classes into another, a fatal error is generated stating:

> error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before  ' xxx '

`xxx` is the last line in the .h file that is being imported, i.e.

```
@interface
{ ..
.. 
xxx
}
```

Any ideas what this error means? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instance variables defined in braces in an `@interface` are expected to have a type qualifier at least. e.g.

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject
{
    NSString* xx;
 // ^^^^^^^^^ declared type of xx
}
// methods
@end
```

Also your interface declaration was missing the `@end` at the end